# Repeated measures or not for daily sales data?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, experiment-design

I have a dataset with aggregated daily sales for three stores over three conditions, each during a one-week period. So, for each store, I have 21 daily sales observations.

I'm having issues figuring out if a repeated measures ANOVA would be the most suitable approach or if I should treat every day as an independent observation.

My thinking is that since every observation is for one specified weekday, it would thus make sense to compare Mondays in condition 1 with Mondays in conditions 2 and 3, thus letting the condition define the 3 levels to analyse between (and thus reducing the number of subjects to 7 for each store, one for each weekday and store, in total 7*3=21 subjects).

I've searched but am unsure if this is an appropriate way of utilizing the increased power that a repeated measures design allows for. If anyone have any thoughts (or/and good ideas on where to read up on this), I would truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it seems that a three-way ANOVA (store x day x condition) might be adequate.

Creating artificial "subjects" as combinations of store and weekday might be better only if you have reason to believe that sales in different stores react differently to week days; but that would also emerge in the form of a significant (store x day) interaction term in the 3-way ANOVA.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response - truly appreciate it.

Comment: The answer above does not answer the question whether to account for dependencies between the data-points (repeated measures), or not. Data-points are nested within shops and daily sales may correlate over time. Merely including shop as a fixed-effect does not solve the issue. Errors will not be independent, inference flawed. The crucial question is: what is your subject? Do you want to make claims about the effects of your conditions on stores in general, or within these three particular stores?

Comment: It is true. From the wording of the question I assumed that conditional on day of week effect,  sales are assumed independent (as well as independent across stores, which would not be the case if stores were in close proximity or affected by similar events different than 'day' and 'condition').